# Adding worksheet to the excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

Just assume I have 3 tables. I want to insert tables in 3 work sheets (per page one table) into a single excel file (without need of ActiveXObject)

[image]

I tried following code, but its creating only one worksheet

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        }, format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
    return function (table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {
            worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
            table: table.innerHTML
        }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})();
```

Comment: You can't use that approach for multiple sheets.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any idea to add sheets because its urgent requirement for me. I need any solution for this case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach you have shown uses a mixture of Spreadsheet XML and HTML. With this mixture it is not possible to fill multiple worksheets. To do this we have to use only Spreadsheet XML consequently. This is because only XML can describe multiple worksheets. The HTML table data is not related to any worksheets except the active worksheet.

To use only Spreadsheet XML is possible, but then we have to work carefully with data types. If Excel imports HTML, it tries to detect data types as if the user would enter the values into cells manually. With XML it does not so. It takes the given data types from the XML. If they do not fit, then it produces errors. So in my example, I use "data-" attríbutes to describe the data-type, data-style and data-value. So it is possible to have the data-value different from the data presentation within the HTML table cell (TD). Since HTML is a format for data presentation and not for data exchange, this is also good practice in my opinion.

For Spreadsheet XML see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066.aspx

The example uses data URI as download link, so it works only with browsers that support this. It will not work with Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
      + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
      + '<Styles>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '</Styles>' 
      + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
    , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
    , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
      var ctx = "";
      var workbookXML = "";
      var worksheetsXML = "";
      var rowsXML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
          rowsXML += '<Row>'
          for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
            var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
            var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
            var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
            dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
            var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
            dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
            ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                   , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                   , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                   , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                  };
            rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
          }
          rowsXML += '</Row>'
        }
        ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";
      }

      ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
      workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

console.log(workbookXML);

      var link = document.createElement("A");
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
      link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
      link.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  })();
</script> 

<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Rebate (10%)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="1980-03-23">Mar 23 1980</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="1234.56">$ 1,234.56</td>
    <td data-formula="=RC[-1]/10" data-type="Number" data-style="Currency">$ 123.45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="1978-11-05">Nov 05 1978</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="2345.67">$ 2,345.67</td>
    <td data-formula="=RC[-1]/10" data-type="Number" data-style="Currency">$ 234.56</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="tbl2">
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Available</td>
    <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bred</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="1.89">$ 1.89</td>
    <td data-type="Boolean" data-value="1">yes</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-value="123">123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value=".89">$ .89</td>
    <td data-type="Boolean" data-value="0">no</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-value="0">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['Customers','Products'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
<button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['Customers','Products'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Calc')">Export to Calc</button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/

Greetings

Axel

Comment: I copy this same code into a xhtml (JSF 2.2) and I get the next error "The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.". I looked on internet, but I didn't find the solution. If anyone could help me, I will be grateful

Comment: This script is pure JavaScript and must run within a browser. The JSFiddle works for me with Firefox browser. No idea what you are doing with JSF 2.2.

Comment: Although it works fine, but it fails to detect colspan and rowspans

Comment: @Saeed Jassani: This approach is outdated. I will not bothering myself with this anymore. There are JavaScript libraries in the wild which can really creating Excel files. [DataTables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks for referring. Will try out

Comment: @Saeed Jassani: Although DataTables is very opulent, if the aim is exporting multiple worksheets in one Excel file, then [SheetJS/js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) could be better because this is a little bit complicated using DataTables. See [Exporting with Multiple Sheets](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/664) for an example.

Comment: Is there an option out there for tables with large data sets?  This crashes with a "Download - Failed - Netowrk Error" in crhome with tables of more than 5000 records.

Comment: Please read my comment from Dec 29 '17 at 7:11. This approach is outdated. The error is because using this approach of course the whole data needs to be transported in one `data:` URI.