# Export HTML table to excel in several worksheet

Tags: javascript, excel, export

I had to export some table to excel, in several worksheet.

I used Axel's code on this topic : [Adding worksheet to the excel file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301811/adding-worksheet-to-the-excel-file-using-javascript)

Everything seems to work fine, but export don't start; browser console show an XML log, I don't know how to solve this issue.

I think that issue is about the HTML table. Did someone know this problem?

[Here are a test for Axel's code](http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/)

And here are his table :

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Rebate (10%)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="1980-03-23">Mar 23 1980</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="1234.56">$ 1,234.56</td>
    <td data-formula="=RC[-1]/10" data-type="Number" data-style="Currency">$ 123.45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="1978-11-05">Nov 05 1978</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="2345.67">$ 2,345.67</td>
    <td data-formula="=RC[-1]/10" data-type="Number" data-style="Currency">$ 234.56</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table id="tbl2">
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Available</td>
    <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bred</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="1.89">$ 1.89</td>
    <td data-type="Boolean" data-value="1">yes</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-value="123">123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value=".89">$ .89</td>
    <td data-type="Boolean" data-value="0">no</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-value="0">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['Customers','Products'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
<button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['Customers','Products'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Calc')">Export to Calc</button>
```

Here is an extract of my code to build HTML table :

```
for(var j=0;j<nbData;j++){
if(j==0){
    /*Gerer le premier affichage (Entete tableau)*/
    affData += "<BR/><center><table id=\"tableToExport_"+i+"\" class=\"donnees\"><tr class=\"titre\"><td>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[j].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue+"</td><td></td></tr>"
}
var date = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[j].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
var val = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[j].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
affData += "<tr>";
    affData += '<td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="'+date.substring(0,date.length-7)+'">'+date.substring(0,date.length-7)+'</td>';
    //affData += '<td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="'+date.substring(0,date.length-16)+'">'+date.substring(0,date.length-16)+'</td>';
    affData += '<td data-type="Number">'+val+"</td>";
affData += "</tr>";
if(j==nbData-1){
    /*Gerer le dernier affichage (Fermer tableau)*/
    affData += "</table></center><BR/>";
}
```

}

This is one of the table to export :

```html
<table id="tableToExport_0">
<tbody>
  <tr class="titre">
    <td>Title</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="2015-01-21 00:03:59">2015-01-21 00:03:59</td>
    <td data-type="Number">71.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="2015-01-21 00:09:00">2015-01-21 00:09:00</td>
    <td data-type="Number">72.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="2015-01-21 00:14:00">2015-01-21 00:14:00</td>
    <td data-type="Number">65.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="2015-01-21 00:19:00">2015-01-21 00:19:00</td>
    <td data-type="Number">75.0</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please, what's wrong?

[EDIT]
Here is my fully code :

```js
dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 height:  400,
 width: 500,
 modal: true,
 buttons: {
  "Export to Excel": function() {
   var test=true;
   var valeurI = 0;
   var tables = new Array();
   var wsName = new Array();
   for(var i=0;test;i++){
    var tab = document.getElementById("tableToExport_"+i)
    if(tab==null){
     test = false;
     valeurI = i;
    }else{
     tables.push('tableToExport_'+i);
     wsName.push('Worksheet_'+i);
    }
   }
   //tablesToExcel(['tableToExport_0','tableToExport_1'], ['Customers','Products'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel');
   tablesToExcel(tables, wsName, 'DataReport.xls', 'Excel');
   //exportToExcel();
   //alert( "Export_"+getTimeDataReport());
   },
  "Cancel": function() {
   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   }, 
 },
 close: function(){}
});

var tablesToExcel = (function() {
 var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
     , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
       + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Benjamin BACKX</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
       + '<Styles>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '</Styles>' 
       + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
     , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
     , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
     , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
     , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
   return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
     var ctx = "";
     var workbookXML = "";
     var worksheetsXML = "";
     var rowsXML = "";

     for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
       if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
       for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
         rowsXML += '<Row>'
         for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
           var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
           var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
           var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
           dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
           var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
           dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
           ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                  , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                  , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                  , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                 };
           rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
         }
         rowsXML += '</Row>'
       }
       ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
       worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
       rowsXML = "";
     }

     ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
     workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

console.log(workbookXML);

     var link = document.createElement("A");
     link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
     link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
     link.target = '_blank';
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
     document.body.removeChild(link);
   }
 })();

function getTimeDataReport() {
 var today=new Date();
 var h=today.getHours();
 var m=today.getMinutes();
 var ddd=today.getDate()+'';
 var mmm=today.getMonth()+1+'';
 var yyy=today.getFullYear()+'';
 var dateToReturn = yyy+mmm+ddd+'_'+h+m;
 return dateToReturn;
}

function afficherData(plant, dateDebut, dateFin, domain, equipement, tableHiddenCB, dataType){

 
  var action = "AFFICHER_DATAS";
 var affData = "";
 var xhr = getXhr();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
   var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
      var lenghtXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("objDesc").length;
    for(var i=0;i<lenghtXml;i++){
     var nbData = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("objDesc")[i].childNodes.length;
     for(var j=0;j<nbData;j++){
      if(j==0){
       /*Gerer le premier affichage (Entete tableau)*/
       affData += "<BR/><center><table id=\"tableToExport_"+i+"\" class=\"donnees\"><tr class=\"titre\"><td>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[j].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue+"</td><td></td></tr>"
      }
      var date = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[j].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
      var val = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[j].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
      affData += "<tr>";
       affData += '<td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="'+date.substring(0,date.length-7)+'">'+date.substring(0,date.length-7)+'</td>';
       //affData += '<td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="'+date.substring(0,date.length-16)+'">'+date.substring(0,date.length-16)+'</td>';
       affData += '<td data-type="Number">'+val+"</td>";
      affData += "</tr>";
      if(j==nbData-1){
       /*Gerer le dernier affichage (Fermer tableau)*/
       affData += "</table></center><BR/>";
      }
     }
    }
   affData += "";
   $("#dialog-form").html(affData);
   dialog.dialog( "open" );
  }        
 }
 xhr.open("POST", "../Servlet",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("...parameters...");
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example with your full code. Your sample table works with my code. Only the data-values for DateTime have to be in the format data-value="2015-01-21T00:19:00". See http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/35/

Comment: Untested but an attempt: Replace `document.body.appendChild(link);` and `document.body.removeChild(link);` with `dialog["0"].appendChild(link);` and `dialog["0"].removeChild(link);`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here you can can the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/X_AB/tk0h7fm6/

Comment: It Works fine, Thank :)
Can you explain the difference please?

Comment: My originally solution is not related to jQuery. It is pure Javascript. But you are using jQuery Dialog. In this case the `document.body` is not in the same scope as the rest of the jQuery code. So `document.body.appendChild(link)` will work, but the `link` then is out of scope so `link.click()` will do nothing. The `dialog["0"].appendChild(link)` or `document.getElementById("dialog-form").appendChild(link)` appends the link in the right scope.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with jQuery. So there certainly is a better solution with jQuery elements. Thats why I post this not as an answer. Maybe someone other will post such a better solution with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery, javascipt, I always be confused with both of them :S By the way, thank you very much!

Comment: Hello Axel. I need to adapt your code.
With those few line, I'm able to export all that I want to excel, a very good point.
But in excel, columns need to be enlarged, at least, fit to the title (first line).
Could you please add some comments in your code, in order to help me understand how it work, and help me to personnalize it?

Comment: Performing fitting column widths ist not easy with Spreadsheet XML. The only approach I could think about is to have a `<Column ss:Width="..."/>` with `...` replaced by calculated widths for each column. Please ask a separate question, provide a jsfiddle with your current code and describe how the desired output with enlarged column widths shall look like. Then I will show you my approach and maybe someone other will have other approaches. If you had asked the separate question then provide a link to this in a comment from here. So I will take notice of this.